# Chart.js onClick function for bar graph

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chart.js

Hi I am trying to create a bar graph with data from my database. I've been fiddling around with the "options:" as well as trying several solutions online but to no avail. Placing the "options:" tag in various parts of my code either causes it to do nothing at all or make the entire bar graph disappear.

```
$(document).ready(function(){




$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8548/chartjs/data.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var exercise = [];
        var count = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            exercise.push("Exercise " + data[i].exercisesId);
            count.push(data[i].total);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: exercise,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: 'Exercises Completed',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: count,
                }]


        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartdata

        });

        options:{onClick: graphClickEvent}
        function graphClickEvent(event, array){
            if(array[0]){
                foo.bar; 
            }
        }

    },



    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
});
```

This is the snippet of code that I have tried placing in various parts of my code:

```
    options:{
    onClick: graphClickEvent
}

function graphClickEvent(event, array){
    if(array[0]){
        foo.bar; 
    }
}
```

I understand that even if that snippet were to work nothing would happen as well but I don't get why placing it within certain areas in the bottom half of my code would cause the aforementioned problem.

Just for background my bar graph is displaying the total number of times a certain exercise is completed and I am trying to make it such that when a specific bar is clicked a display of some sort would pop up with a list of people who have completed the exercise. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think only this is needed

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d");
```

Comment: Where would I place it then?